# How to send an email -ajax asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried to create this "send an email" for my app using ajax (it's a requirement for my project), but it's only returning json, not even the message "your message was sent". I've looked through many sites and question, but they were not helpful.

index.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendEmailAjax", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess = "DisplayConfirmation"
}))
 {
        <label for="from">From: </label>
        <input type="text" name="FromEmail" id="from" />
        <br />
        <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Subject" id="subject" />
        <br />
        <label for="message">Message: </label>
        <input type="text" name="MessageText" id="message" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />

 }

<div id="formresult"></div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<script>
    function DisplayConfirmation(result) {
        var confirmation = "Message was sent!";
        $('#formresult').html(confirmation);
    }
</script>
```

emailconfirmation.cshtml, email.cshtml

```
@model Project.Models.MessageDetails

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmailConfirmation";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Congratulatons!</h2>

<div>
    You sent a message:
    <p>
        @Model.MessageText
    </p>
</div>
```

emailcontroller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Project.Models;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class EmailController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendEmail(MessageDetails message)
        {
            return View("EmailConfirmation", message);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendEmailAjax(MessageDetails message)
        {
            return Json(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you wan to do? i mean you want to display "Message was sent". please elobrate

Comment: I want it to actually send the email, i've read somewhere that you can do that by using smtp client, but i'm not sure if it's posiible with ajax?

Comment: Yes you can send mail with help of SMTP, I hope you are trying to sending email on ajax call. Am i right?

Comment: Yes. So you suggest i use the smtp?

Comment: Yes when ajax call hit code behind function , use SMTP library to send email in that code behind function. Let me know if you need sample code for smtp

Comment: If you were so kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is standard code to send email via SMTP. Modify below code according to your change and keep this code in SendEmailAjax method controller. if you are using any organization SMPT server then make sure that IT team allowed you to send email via SMTP. for testing purpose you can use gmail SMTP with your gmail account credentials.

Change or modify below code according to you change:

```
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.xxxxx.com");
        smtp.Timeout = 300000;
        mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@xxxxx.com");
        mail.To.Add("receiver@yyyy.com");
        mail.CC.Add("receivercc@yyyy.com");
        mail.Subject = "My Subject";
        mail.Body = "This is a testing mail";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        smtp.Send(mail);
```

For gmail SMTP configuration, you need to tweak smtp configuration like below :

```
      SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
      smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "password here");  
      smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;  
      smtp.Send(mail);
```

refer this article for more details:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/send-email-using-gmail-smtp

let me know if you need more details.